# Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Network is unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For the past few weeks I have been using a redis server locally on Windows 10 using WSL 2/Ubuntu 20.04 and now suddenly I can't connect to the server anymore. Here is what I usually did in linux terminal that opens when you run ubuntu using wsl 2:

```
$ sudo service redis-server start
$ sudo service redis-server status
* redis-server running
```

But now if I try to run the `redis-cli` command I get this error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Network is unreachable
```

I have checked  the ip and port using:

```
$ ps aux | grep redis
```

which returns

```
redis      190  0.2  0.0  51704  9796 ?        Ssl  17:12   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

From what I can tell this is telling me that the server is running at 127.0.0.1:6379 yet I cannot connect to it.
Every post I can find on this kind of issue shows the error as

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection Refused
```

instead of "network is unreachable" so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Sounds like you have no loopback interface. Check `ifconfig`. You can try running `sudo ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 && sudo route add -net 127.0.0.0` to fix it, but normally the OS set this up automatically, so maybe something else is messed up in your system as well...

Comment: I tried to use ifconfig but had to use ```sudo apt install net-tools``` to use ifconfig. The install failed. The error I get: ```E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1_am``` --- so I can't use ifconfig

Answer (score 1):

The issues is with Firewall settings its either windows Firewall or else WSL Ubuntu Firewall which refuse to connect via port.

Opening Port :

Windows : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall

Ubuntu (WSL) : `sudo ufw allow <port number>`

Other linux distor refer : https://www.journaldev.com/34113/opening-a-port-on-linux

This Solved the issue for me.

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu WSL command: `sudo ufw allow 6379`